# The object is null after the event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern in my application. Basically I have a main View and several child views.

In the main ViewModel, I have the instances of each child ViewModels. Now in an event in the main ViewModel.

I have

```
private void Child_B_Grid_SelectedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Child_C_ViewModel.SelectedItem = Child_B_ViewModel.SelectedItem;
}

 public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.selectedItem)
            {
                this.selectedItem = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
```

It works, after that the program returns to the Child View C. I want to use the SelectedItem I just got in a button event in code behind.

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.ViewModel.Save();
    }
```

But `SelectedItem` is null. Not sure why?

Comment: You might want to debug your code and set a breakpoint on your SelectedItems's setter. Sounds like you have multiple instances of your ViewModel

Comment: @lokusking, I found the error and post my solution. But I am still not sure why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOps.

After I add a View load event, I get the value.

```
private void View_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is ViewModel)
    {
        this.ViewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
    }
    else
    {
        this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    }
}
```

Originally I didn't have the Load event. I am not exactly sure why I need it. Original I just put the code in the constructor such as:

```
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
```